# PHP blowfish encrypted string, how to decrypt in Lazarus

Tags: php, encryption, lazarus, blowfish

I have code in PHP to encrypt string using blowfish and sha256 hash:

```
<?php
    $plaintext = "Secret text";
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="BF-CBC");
    $iv = '1234567812345678';
    $key = 'password';
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode( $ciphertext_raw );
    echo "encrypted string:<br>$ciphertext2<br><br>";
?>
```

And I have code in Lazarus for decrypt this string:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, 
  DCPblowfish, DCPsha256, base64;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    DCP_blowfish1: TDCP_blowfish;
    DCP_sha256_1: TDCP_sha256;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  

implementation

{$R *.frm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Cipher: TDCP_blowfish;
    iv: string;
    KeyStr: string;
    encrypted_string: string;
    decrypted_string: string;
begin
    memo1.lines.clear;
    encrypted_string := 'text from php';
    KeyStr := 'password';   
    iv := '1234567812345678';
    Cipher := TDCP_blowfish.Create(Self);
    Cipher.InitStr(KeyStr, TDCP_sha256);        
    cipher.SetIV(iv);
    decrypted_string := Cipher.DecryptString(DecodeStringBase64(encrypted_string));
    memo1.lines.add(decrypted_string);
    Cipher.Burn;
    Cipher.Free;
    Dest.Free;
        
end;

end.
```

But decrypted string is not that what I'm expecting :(
Where are my mistakes? Or what is the simplest method to encrypt string using blowfish in PHP and decrypt in Lazarus(using DCPCrypt?) ?
Thanks

## UPDATE:

I've changed code to use files instead of plaintext strings
PHP:

```
<?php
    $plaintext = "secret";
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="BF-CBC");
    $iv = '12345678';
    $key = hash('sha256', 'password');
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    file_put_contents('file.enc', $ciphertext_raw);
?>
```

Lazarus:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Cipher: TDCP_blowfish;
    Source, Dest: TFileStream;
    iv: string;
  begin
    stream:= TStream.create;
    KeyStr := 'password';
    iv := '12345678';
    Source:= TFileStream.Create('file.enc',fmOpenRead);   
        Dest:= TFileStream.Create(Edit2.Text,fmCreate);   
        Cipher := TDCP_blowfish.Create(Self);
        Cipher.InitStr(KeyStr,TDCP_sha256);    
        cipher.SetIV(iv);
        Cipher.DecryptStream(Source,Dest,Source.Size); 

        Cipher.Burn;
        Cipher.Free;
        Dest.Free;
        Source.Free;
  end;
```

and it's still doesn't working :(

Comment: Encoding algorithms operate on binary data, not text. Your code is making assumptions about text encoding. What are these assumptions?

Comment: I don't know the assumptions.. but I've modified code and now its using files, not plaintext:

Comment: PHP:
```
<?php
 $plaintext = "secret text";
 $iv = '12345678';
 $key = 'password';
 $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
 file_put_contents('file.enc', $ciphertext_raw);
?>
```

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
...
    stream:= TStream.create;
    KeyStr := 'password';
        iv := '12345678';
        Source:= TFileStream.Create('file.enc',fmOpenRead);  
        Dest:= TFileStream.Create('file.dec',fmCreate);    
        Cipher := TDCP_blowfish.Create(Self);
        Cipher.InitStr(KeyStr,TDCP_sha256);          
        cipher.SetIV(iv);
        Cipher.DecryptStream(Source,Dest,Source.Size);
        Cipher.Burn;
        Cipher.Free;
        Dest.Free;
        Source.Free;
    stream.free;
  end;

Comment: and its still don't working

Comment: In the PHP-code I do not see any SHA256-hashing at all - why do you use it on Lazarus-side? And kindly [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65653646/edit) your post and add the FileStream code there - we can't "read" the code in comments, thanks.

Comment: my mistake, there is $key = hash('sha256', 'password');  instead of $key = 'password';

Comment: If `$iv` is an Initialisation Vector value then this should not be static. IV's should be unique or random or otherwise non-linear and non-static depending on your method of encryption. Your IV in PHP and in Lazerus are different.

Comment: `encrypted_string := 'text from php';` And did you base64 decode this string?

Comment: yes, there is:  decrypted_string := Cipher.DecryptString(DecodeStringBase64(encrypted_string));  later in the code

Comment: so how can I do the iv   vector to be the same in php and lazarus?

Comment: Usually the iv is generated randomly on sender = encryption side and **prepended** to the ciphertext. As there is no need to keep the iv secret and we know the length of the iv (16 bytes for AES) its not a big job to strip the first 16 bytes on decryption (Lazarus) side and provide it to the decryption function.

Comment: in my case, whole encrypted file has only 8bytes. I don't think there is iv inside.